# cannot get flash to use external files

Tags: flash, csv

I'm trying to write a Flash program (using CS6 and AS3) that will extract data from an external .csv for my company (so that someone could change the .csv to change the output on a day to day basis).

What I've discovered is that it works perfectly fine within Flash Creator, but if I publish it to the .swf it throws a security error.

I discovered that you have to go to a webpage in a browser and manually allow specific files.  Unfortunately, this program is going to eventually live on a website, when we uploaded it to the website it didn't work for this reason so my question is:

Is there a way to make that manual allowance on a webpage (we do have access to the server or is there another way to allow a .swf to access external files over the internet (.csv is stored online) ?

If it's relevant I'm using URLLoader to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the web server that hosts the CSV file? A proper crossdomain.xml there should let your Flash code access the file.

Personally, I would just write a PHP script or set up mod_proxy to fetch the file on the server-side to avoid the client-side cross-domain issue altogether.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of crossdomain.xml files.